# Conversion from Obj C to C#

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uikeyboard

I am trying to convert this piece of code to C#, the code is from Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

```
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size; 

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;

scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);

    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
```

So far this is my attempt, I am getting stuck at the CGRectValue.

```
                    NSDictionary info = n.UserInfo;

        SizeF kbSize = ((RectangleF)info[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey]).Size;

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0.0f, 0.0f, kbSize.Height, 0.0f);

        this.uiScrollView.ContentInset = contentInsets;
        this.uiScrollView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        RectangleF aRect = this.View.Frame;

        aRect.Size.Height -= kbSize.Height;

        if(!aRect.Contains(_currentField.Frame))
        {
            PointF scrollPoint = new PointF(0.0f, _currentField.Frame.Y - kbSize.Height);
            this.uiScrollView.SetContentOffset(scrollPoint, true);
        }
```

I am probably not using the right type, can someone please help me out, or some alternative code doing similar thing. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I am getting stuck at the CGRectValue." Does the debugger show that all the previously referred to variables have the values you would expect? What does the debugger show about aRect after aRect = self.view.frame?

Comment: I cannot convert that line to C# code. It does not compile. Please see the C# code I tried.

Comment: How do you get `_currentField`? I'm also converting the tutorial *[iOS SDK: Keeping Content From Underneath the Keyboard](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard--mobile-6103)* ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something else wrong with your C# code.

```
aRect.Size.Height -= kbSize.Height;
```

`Size` is of type `System.Drawing.SizeF` which is a struct (i.e. a value-type). Changing it's value won't be propagated back to the to `aRect` instance (this is a .NET behavior).

What you should do is:

```
aRect.Height -= kbSize.Height;
```

which will be reduce actually the `aRect` size (not the `Size` struct which won't be assigned back to the `RectangleF`).

Comment: Thanks for a good catch. That actually was a bug in my translation. Now, it's working better, but not sure why the UITextField still jumps up a bit when I start to type, even though it's already visible just on top of the keyboard. Any suggestion?

Comment: Not without seeing how well it jumps ;-) but if you can create a small, self-contained test case that shows the behaviour then attach it to a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: All right, will do. In the mean time, could you please let me know if there is any other sample of a fix for this issue, ie making the textfield visible when the keyboard is over it. I could not find a good working sample so far for monotouch. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not aware of any issue. Calling `textfield. BecomeFirstResponder ();` should handle this **or** maybe I'm not understanding your issue correctly? In any case it would likely be quicker to ask another question, with a full description (and working ObjC code if you have it) since it would allow many other people to view it.

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out:

```
((NSValue)info[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey]).RectangleFValue.Size
```

That should work. Although I could not make it work like I wanted, that line of code would actually compile and translate to the Obj C code.

Comment: `var kbSize = ((NSValue)info[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey]).CGRectValue.Size;`